# Consumir un Webservices soap

Tags: java, webservice, soap, ejb, jax-ws

Tengo una consulta como puedo parsear la respuesta de un webservices soap en java usando el api de java , JAX-WS.

Answer (score 0):

Hola Si utilizas el IDE Netbeans lo puedes consumir con el funcion de cliente que posee este ide.

Nuevo Proyecto -> JavaApplication.

Click derecho sobre el proyecto ->Nuevo 
Luego Selecciona ->Web Service Client.

Si no lo tienes debes de instalar Java EE.

Luego eliges la opcion consumir desde URL.

Una vez completado este proceso automaticamente seran creadas todas las clases necesarias para consumir el servicio.

Puedes encontrar bastante informacion en esta Pagina:

[Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html)